# Bullet points appear below a multi select drop down box when selecting an option

Tags: css, angular, multi-select

I am building an angular(7 is the version) page that has a multi select dropdown  for which I am using [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown). Please see the below picture - [image] When I click on the dropdown and try to select or unselect an option, then these blue dots appear ( only when selecting or deselcting). Any idea how can I get rid of them? If I inspect the element, it doesn't give any clue.
 Note: I have done some customization to the multi-select-dropdown styling, tried removing them, that doesn't solve this problem.

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown name="selectedOptions"
           tabindex="3"
           [data]="dropdownList"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions"
           [settings]="dropdownSettings"
           (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
           (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

css

```
.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.52857143;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
}

.multiselect-dropdown:focus {
    outline: 0px !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
}

.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn span.ng-star-inserted { padding-right: 14px; }

.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .dropdown-down {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

}

.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .dropdown-up {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

}

.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .selected-item {
    background: #111 !important;
    border: 1px solid #111 !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0 !important;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn .selected-item:hover {
    background-color: #00a7ea !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.multiselect-item-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + div:before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: '';
    color: #111 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    border: 2px solid #111 !important;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.multiselect-item-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div:before {
    -webkit-animation: .2s ease-in borderscale;
    animation: .2s ease-in borderscale;
    background: #111 !important;
}
```

Comment: try to add your code in code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel : added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the above problem by adding a class="multiselect-dropdown" to the ng-multiselect-dropdown and then overriding the 'focus' styles.

```
.multiselect-dropdown:focus {
outline: 0px !important;
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
outline: 0px solid #111;
```

}